# how to display the result of the search in a table using php

Tags: php, foreach, html-table, readfile

I have php script that read from txt files and display the result after allow the user to enter a string to search.

The system display the user request with the filename and line number.
 as it show in the uploaded image .

[result displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXqzN.png)

what I need is to make each column contain the **file name**  and the rows will contain **line number**.

[requested design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxNfn.png)

the result based on Mirza's answer

[displayed result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMyRm.png)

last result

[last result in table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHGTI.png)

ScreenShot

[based on latest update of Mirza answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4UIv.png)

## text to test

> سيلان الطاقة الحرارية من البيئة وإليها. وعادة ما يطلق هذا الاسم على
>   ظاهرة ارتفاع درجات حرارة الأرض عن معدلها الطبيعي. وقد ازداد المعدل
>   العالمي لدرجة حرارة الهواء عند سطح الأرض ب0.74 ± 0.18 °C خلال المائة
>   عام المنتهية سنة 2005. وحسب اللجنة الدولية لتغير المناخ(IPCC) فان
>   "أغلب الزيادة الملحوظة في معدل درجة الحرارة العالمية منذ منتصف القرن
>   العشرين تبدو بشكل كبير نتيجة لزيادة غازات الاحتباس الحراري (غازات
>   البيت الزجاجي) التي تبعثها النشاطات التي يقوم بها البشر.
>
> تخترق أغلب أشعة الشمس الغلاف الجوي لتصل إلى سطح الأرض وأغلب تلك الأشعة
>   تقع في الطول الموجي المرئي (ضوء الشمس الذي تراه العين) لذلك يحدث تسخين
>   لسطح الأرض أثناء النهار، ولا تستطيع الأرض امتصاص الطاقة الشمسية
>   بالكامل، ولو حدث ذلك فستصل حرارة الأرض إلى درجة الانصهار، وتكون نهاية
>   الحياة عليها.
>
> تسخن الأرض لامتصاص حرارة الشمس، ثم يعيد سطح الأرض إشعاع الطاقة الممتصة
>   مرة أخرى إلى الغلاف الجوي، وعند غياب أي تأثيرات معقدة يحدث اتزان
>   حراري. وفي هذه الحالة تكون درجة حرارة سطح الأرض نحو – 2.3 درجة مئوية،
>   وتكون الطاقة التي تعيد الأرض إشعاعها على صورة أشعة تحت الحمراء (وهذا
>   المثال مخالف للواقع).
>
> وفي الواقع تعقيدات، حيث يحتجز الغلاف الجوي جزءاً من الأشعة تحت
>   الحمراء؛ لوجود جزئيات ثاني أكسيد الكربون وبخار الماء التي تمتص الجزء
>   الأكبر من الأشعة تحت الحمراء، والجزء الذي لا يتم إمتصاصه يخرج من
>   الغلاف الجوي إلى الفضاء، ويعمل الجزء الممتص من الأشعة تحت الحمراء في
>   الغلاف الجوي على رفع درجة الحرارة.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXqzN.png)

## code:

```
<?php

$result = [];
if(isset($_POST["search"]))
{
    $search =$_POST['name'];
    echo "the word  $search exist: <br><br>";
    foreach(glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/readfiletest/*.txt") as $txts)
    {
        $line = 1;
        $temp   = [];
        $myFileLink = fopen($txts, 'r');
        while(!feof($myFileLink))
        {
            $myFileContents = fgets($myFileLink);
            if( preg_match_all('/('.preg_quote($search,'/').')/i', $myFileContents, $matches))
            {

                $temp['filename'] = basename ($txts);
                foreach($matches[1] as $match)
                {
                    $temp['lines'][] = $line;
                }
            }
            ++$line;
        }
        fclose($myFileLink);

        $result[] = $temp;
    }

    //display the table
    echo '<table border=2>';

    $filenameHtml    = '<tr>';
    $lineNumberHtml    = '<tr>';
    foreach ($result as $item){
     $filename = isset($item['filename']) ? $item['filename'] : '';
     $lines = isset($item['lines']) ? implode(',',$item['lines']) : '';
     $filenameHtml .= "<th>$filename</th>";
     $lineNumberHtml .= "<td>$lines</td>";
    }
    $filenameHtml    .= '</tr>';
    $lineNumberHtml  .= '</tr>';

    echo $filenameHtml.$lineNumberHtml;
    echo '</table>';
}
?>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="ar-sa">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <style>
          #form {
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #CCCCCC, #EEEEEE 175px);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #CCCCCC, #EEEEEE 175px);
        background: linear-gradient(bottom, #CCCCCC, #EEEEEE 175px);
        margin: auto;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        position: absolute;


        font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-style: italic;
        line-height: 24px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #09C;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        border: inset 1px solid #333;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      }

    </style
    <body>
    <div id = "form">
        <form action="index.php" method="post">
          <h1 align =center > Search Form </h1>
          <p>enter your string <input type ="text"  id = "idName"  name="name" /></p>
          <p align =center ><input type ="Submit" name ="search" value= "Search" /></p>
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you want to see the result as shown below.

[image]

Please replace the php code as below.

```
<?php

$result = [];
if(isset($_POST["search"]))
{
    $search =$_POST['name'];
    echo "the word  $search exist: <br><br>";
    foreach(glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/readfiletest/*.txt") as $txts)
    {
        $line = 1;
        $temp   = [];
        $myFileLink = fopen($txts, 'r');
        while(!feof($myFileLink))
        {
            $myFileContents = fgets($myFileLink);
            if( preg_match_all('/('.preg_quote($search,'/').')/i', $myFileContents, $matches))
            {

                $temp['filename'] = basename ($txts);
                foreach($matches[1] as $match)
                {
                    $temp['lines'][] = $line;
                }
            }
            ++$line;
        }
        fclose($myFileLink);

        if(!empty($temp)) {
            $result[] = $temp;
        }
    }

    //display the table
    echo '<table border=2>';

    $filenameHtml    = '<tr>';

    foreach ($result as $item) {
        $filename = isset($item['filename']) ? $item['filename'] : '';
        $filenameHtml .= "<th>$filename</th>";

        //this line was not having the concatination
        $lineNumberHtml .= '<td><table width="100%" border=2>';
        foreach($item['lines'] as $line) {
            $lineNumberHtml .= '<tr>';
            $lineNumberHtml .= "<td>$line</td>";
            $lineNumberHtml .= '</tr>';
        }
        $lineNumberHtml .= '</table></td>';

    }
    $filenameHtml    .= '</tr>';


    echo $filenameHtml.$lineNumberHtml;
    echo '</table>';
}
?>
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: no i want to make  the columns contains the file name and the rows will be the line number  i will upload the design  and edit the question

Comment: Please see the updated answer, is this you want?

Comment: yes this what  i want but it did not work it display error :

**Notice: Undefined index: filename in C:\xampp\htdocs\readfiletest\index.php on line 38
========================================
Notice: Undefined index: lines in C:\xampp\htdocs\readfiletest\index.php on line 39
==========================================
implode(): Invalid arguments passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\readfiletest\index.php on line 39**

Comment: updated the answer code, added validation for filename and lines as below `foreach ($result as $item){
            $filename = $item['filename'] ? $item['filename'] : '';
            $lines = $item['lines'] ? implode(',',$item['lines']) : '';
            $filenameHtml    .= "<th>$filename</th>";
            $lineNumberHtml  .= "<td>$lines</td>";
        }`

Comment: still display these lines :

**Notice: Undefined index: filename in C:\xampp\htdocs\readfiletest\index.php on line 40
=======================================
Notice: Undefined index: lines in C:\xampp\htdocs\readfiletest\index.php on line 41**

Comment: can you please add the complete script of yours? I am not getting any notice errors. you need to fix the notice errors but it is outputting the expected result rite?

Comment: this is the whole script  i will display the result in the question take a look

Comment: is it possible to attach the txt files and the search word, so that i can fix for you?

Comment: I THINK THIS LINE cause the error :

$filename = $item['filename'] ? $item['filename'] : '';

i changed to 

**$filename = (!isset($item['filename'])) ? (!isset($item['filename'])) : '';**

but still not working because now  the notice is fixed but it change the result.

Comment: i fixed :

 $filename = isset($item['filename']) ? $item['filename'] : '';
 $lines = isset($item['lines']) ? implode(',',$item['lines']) : '';

Comment: i will edit the question and add the last result because it still have some error

Comment: can you provide me the updated code in your question and txt files to test it

Comment: i edit my question and add the code with the tested text

Comment: Please check the updated answer, hope this helps now !

Comment: no its not working because it just display the line number  in the first column only check the edit question

Comment: Please check the updated answer, need to add the concatenation `$lineNumberHtml .= '<td><table width="100%" border=2>';`, Hope atleast this helps

Comment: i found the solution and fixed the code thank you for your help and your time.

if you can help me now i need to be able when the user click on the file name it open the pdf type of the file.

what i need is to be able to highlight the founded word.is this possible ?